# Format date as dd.mm.yyyy with Moment.js and Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I would like to render the date which is in this format in datatables:
29.01.2021 (today's date for example)

I have tried below code, but it will output as "invalid date".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
...

{ data: 'db_date',
    render: function (data, type, row) {
      return moment(new Date(data).toString()).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    }
}
```

What could be missing? - Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us a sample of the source data (e.g. the JSON, if that is how data is being provided)?

Comment: You need to use moment(inputDateString, inputDateFormat). https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***toString()*** method from the Date object as shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
...

{ data: 'db_date',
    render: function (data, type, row) {
      return moment(new Date(data)).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. So, the invalid date error is gone but if I try to sort the date , it will sort it by year first like this: 31.12.2020... 31.12.2019 .... 31.12.2018. The data comes from MySql and the date field type is (Text) not timestamp

Comment: any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to first sort in Date() format before applying the moment.format() method. (E.g: Text (mysql data) -> convert to Date() objects -> sort -> format using Momentjs)